# SOLVED - REST API composite batch fails - INVALID_BATCH_SIZE

Tags: rest-api, batch

I'm trying to use the new batch REST calls as documented here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_batch.htm#topic-title

But I get the following;

My request body;

```
{"batchRequests":[
  {"method":"PATCH","url":"v34.0/sobjects/account/001D000000K0fXOIAZ","richInput":{"Name":"NewName"}},
  {"method":"GET","url":"v34.0/sobjects/account/001D000000K0fXOIAZ?fields=Name,BillingPostalCode"}
]}
```

The Response

```
[{"errorCode":"INVALID_BATCH_SIZE","message":"No requests found in batch request"}]
```

This was using *services/data/v34.0/composite/batch*.

Has anyone got a working example of this please?

Comment: Make sure you're setting the content-type header correctly (to application/json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the *Content-Type* being set incorrectly... D'oh!

I initially tried my request using curl instead and this worked. Here's the command I used (I have masked my *accessToken*);

```
curl https://eu5.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/composite/batch \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <MY-ACCESS-TOKEN>' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -X POST \
  -d'{"batchRequests":[{"method":"GET","url":"v34.0/sobjects/account/00124000003Q4MF?fields=Name,BillingPostalCode"}]}'
```

I was using the *forcejs* library in my original query, and I had mistakenly assumed that the default content-type was json. Once I had set this correctly then my calls went through just fine.

Thanks all for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Todd,

What you are doing should definitely work.  The endpoint you are posting to looks correct, and the payload is in the correct format.  I would expect you to receive an error, but the error should be 404s since the account you are using does not exist in your system...not an invalid batch size error.

Would you be able to log a case with support and provide:

- The specific way you are submitting the request (Workbench, curl, apex, some custom code)
- Login access granted to your org
- The org id for the org you are testing on

Once you have done that, respond with the case number and I can take a look on our side.

Thanks in advance.
Jay

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that since you are using the ID from the example:

001D000000K0fXOIAZ

That no records matched that ID and thus the query returns no records.

Simply replace the 001D000000K0fXOIAZ with the ID of an existing account in your org

The following works well when execute from the Dev Console but you need the correct ID

```
String bdy = '{"batchRequests":[{"method":"PATCH","url":"v34.0/sobjects/account/001A000000bK0KH","richInput":{"Name":"NewName"}},{"method":"GET","url":"v34.0/sobjects/account/001A000000bK0KH?fields=Name,BillingPostalCode"}]}';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://cs7.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/composite/batch');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody(bdy);
req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + userinfo.getSessionID());
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
system.debug(logginglevel.error,res);
```

Comment: That is worth a shot... thanks.
My thinking however is that it would still result in response relating to the sub-operation, rather than one referencing the batch request itself. I shall tweak this to reflect a REST call that I first validate works outside of the batch.

Comment: I have tried with IDs that I know exist and return values, still no joy sadly.